# Odd error while trying to run ERGM in R

Tags: r

I have a network in R, formatted in pajek(.net) of collaborations. I'm trying to run an ergm analysis on it. I've formatted a similar network and run the same commands successfully, but when we expanded the size of the network, this error has begun to appear.

```
> CollabNet2005ERGM <-ergm(CollabNet05~edges+nodematch("11"))
Error in -object$glm$null.deviance : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Is there a workaround, either on the formatting side of things or within R that will allow me to complete the ERGM?

Comment: You really should make a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you need help debugging code.

Comment: without the original data file, this is going to be very hard to debug.  Perhaps posting a `traceback()` from the error will give us a clue?